# How to pass a Javascript variable as the mp3 file my audio player plays

Tags: javascript, html, audio, media-player

I am trying to make an audio player that takes an mp3 file from JSONP, and sends it to an HTML audio player. The JSONP is not included in this code, I simplified it to have the mp3 file included as a variable. Anyway, I was wondering how to pass that Javascript variable onto the HTML as the src for the audio player. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <script>
        var theFile = 'foo.mp3';
        $("div").html("<audio src= theFile controls preload='auto' autobuffer></audio>");                   
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This explains it better than I can: http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introduction-to-the-html5-audio-tag-javascript-manipulation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("div").html("<audio src='" + theFile + "' controls preload='auto' autobuffer></audio>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use this?

```
 $('div.demo-container').html(function() {
      var emph = '<em>' + $('p').length + ' paragraphs!</em>';
      return '<p>All new content for ' + emph + '</p>';
    });
```

More info in the JQuery .html() Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/html/